# if you merge two tags which had a synonym proposal, the proposal stays, pointing the new tag to itself.

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

On cooking.stackexchange, a user without the rep to propose a tag merge noticed that we don't need both the tags [brining](/questions/tagged/brining) and [brine](/questions/tagged/brine). I first created a synonym proposal pointing from brining to brine. After that, I noticed that there is also a "merge" link (possibly a mod-only functionality) and used it, merging brine into brining, creating a synonym while doing so. I didn't remove the old proposal before that, because I didn't see a way to do it.

As a result of this, now we seem to have been left with brining as a synonym of brining, which is confusing at least (maybe it also has side effects, but we haven't noticed them yet). I think it would be good if this can be prevented from happening somehow, so the next hapless mod can't repeat my mistake.

The merge request is on [Can we add the synonym [brine] for [brining]?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/can-we-add-the-synonym-brine-for-brining/)

Comment: One important and confusing point is that if you go via the synonym suggestion route linked from the tag itself, your mod powers don't work, you still only suggest a synonym. If you use the synonym page linked in the mod tools you immediately create a synonym without voting. I would recommend to generally use the `/tags/synonyms` page. You might also be able to delete the synonym suggestion there.